# Getting illegal format error while executing program in java

Tags: java

I want to show a table to user

```
Name quantity Price Total
a    2        3.0   6.0
```

properly indented.
Also, i need to take care of maximum allow values for all parameters such as 30 for name and 10 for remaining all 
I am executing below lines in java:

```
System.out.println("Name\tquantity\tPrice\tTotal");
        System.out.printf("%1$30s\t %.10d\t %.10f\t %.10f", product_name, productQuantity, itemprice, productQuantity*itemprice);
```

I am getting the below error:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException
```

Comment: What are the types of values you are supplying to `printf`?

Comment: its string, int, double and double

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `%d` specifier, which requires an integer argument, but you may be giving it a parameter other than that e.g. `String`. Or may be a negative value other than -1. Quoted from [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IllegalFormatPrecisionException.html):

> Unchecked exception thrown when the precision is a negative value
>   other than -1, the conversion does not support a precision, or the
>   value is otherwise unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%-` format to pad number/string with whitespaces to the right:

```
System.out.printf("%-30s %-10s %-10s %s\n", "Name", "quantity", "Price", "Total");
System.out.printf("%-30s %-10d %-10.1f %-10.1f", "product", 2, (float) 6.1, 2 * 6.1);
```

Result:

```
Name                           quantity   Price      Total
product                        2          6,1        12,2
```

Also, you have error in yours format string:

```
"%1$30s\t %.10d\t %.10f\t %.10f"
"%1$ <- here
```

That `1$` is breaking yours format string, thus shifting format parameters by 1, so `product` argument (a string) is actually substituted for second format arg (`%.10d`), which expects a number.

So, as string formatters doesn't support `.n` precision specifiers, `IllegalFormatPrecisionException` is thrown.

**Upd.**

In order to get rid of that error, you should either remove `1$` specifier, or add it to *all* of args:

```
System.out.printf("%1$30s\t %2$10s\t %3$10s\t %4$10s\n", "Name", "quantity", "Price", "Total");
System.out.printf("%1$30s\t %2$10d\t %3$10f\t %4$10f\n", "product", (int)2, (float)6, (float)2*6);
```

Result:

```
                          Name     quantity       Price       Total
                       product            2    6,000000   12,000000
```

More nifty formatting:

```
System.out.printf("%1$30s\t %2$10s\t %3$10s\t %4$10s\n", "Name", "quantity", "Price", "Total");
System.out.printf("%1$30s\t %2$10d\t %3$10.1f\t %4$10.1f\n", product, (int)amount, (float)price, (float)(amount * price));
```

Gives:

```
                          Name     quantity       Price       Total
                       product            2         6,1        12,2
```

Comment: thanks but that indentation would break if string and numbers exceed the limit

Comment: @Aquarius24, but `%1$` -related part _do_ fixes yours `IllegalFormatPrecisionException` error, right? Look at update. Mark answer as accepted, if it does =) Also, if `string and numbers exceed the limit`, indentation would break anyway...